# Как в ElasticSearch выполнить поиск по точному совпадению в нескольких полях?

Tags: elasticsearch

Имеется вот такой маппинг:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "test": {
                "properties": {
                    "testlinks": {
                        "properties": {
                            "field_one": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "whitespace"
                            },
                            "field_two": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "analyzer": "whitespace"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Оба поля могут содержать значения вида: **абв-12/гд** , **абв-12**, **абв12** (т.е. могут содержать знаки препинания).

Задача: найти документы где поля testlinks.field_one **и** testlinks.field_two **точно** соответствуют указанным значениям.

Например, документ "Документ 1" содержит данные:

```
{
    "index": "test",
    "id": "3Ttv6m0BXeo9lU95PytX",
    "body": {
        "title": "\u0414\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442 1",
        "testlinks": [
            {
                "field_one": "test1",
                "field_two": "1"
            },
            {
                "field_one": "test2",
                "field_two": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Если запросить:
**testlinks.field_one = "test1" AND field_two = "2"** - ничего не должно найти

А если запросить:
**testlinks.field_one = "test2" AND field_two = "2"** - документ должно найти

Как это сделать?

Возможно нужно как-то изменить маппинг. 
Буду очень признателен за подсказку!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена через nested query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "testlinks",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "testlinks.field_one": "test1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "testlinks.field_two": "1"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно кому-то пригодится.